# Facebook auth keeps redirecting

Tags: facebook

I want to setup a facebook php post to wall, but after the facebook auth, the code just keep redirecting with different token, can anyone help me?   Thanks very much!!

here's my sample url: http://for-winner.com/fff.php

```php
require_once ("fb/src/facebook.php");

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => 'id',
        'secret' => 'secret',
        'cookie' => true
    ));

$attachment = array(
    'message' => 'hello',

  );

$user = $facebook->getUser(); 
if($user == 0) {
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params = array('scope' => "publish_stream"));
    echo ("<script> top.location.href='".$login_url."'</script>");
} else { $token=$facebook->getAccessToken();

    try {
        $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $attachment);
    } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                            'scope' => 'publish_stream'
                         )); 
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead -

```php
$canvas_page = "https://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAMESPACE/MY_CURRENT_PAGE.php;
$auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page)."&scope=publish_stream";
$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
if (empty($data["user_id"])) 
{
   echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
} 
else 
{
   // you code 
}
```